# Django form to enter/save html to database

Tags: django

I'm in my first week of Django development and am working on an admin page that will let me write some quick html using TinyMCE and then save it to the database. I don't need to display this web page on the site or add it to urls.py, etc. The html snippet will be loaded from the database and used in a view function.

I've read in "Practical Django Projects" how to integrate TinyMCE, so my question is more concerned with the best approach for the form itself. Specifically:

**1.** Is there a built-in form like flatpage that works well for this? I only need one field in the form for the html.

**2.** How do I save the form's text after it's entered?

I created a model with a JSONField to save the html in, but I'm not clear on what to do next. Thanks.

Comment: What part would you like explained better? Basically an admin user will be able to log in and go to a flatpage-like page where they enter a html snippet. Once they're done they click a save button and the html they entered is saved to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [ModelAdmin](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) class to get what I wanted. I created a new model in models.py and then used ModelAdmin to enable an admin-editable form for the model's data.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

here is the documentation for [Django Flatpages App](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/?from=olddocs), maybe you serve.